# Building native extensions. This could take a while

Tags: ruby, osx-mavericks

I have trouble updating gems on my machine

- osx 10.9.2
- xcode upadted, command line tools installed
- ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]

I do:

```
$ sudo gem update
Password:
Updating installed gems
Updating bigdecimal
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
```

It just stuck here, I can wait whole day nothing happens, I just see my fan speed gets to 6k.
Im not familiar with ruby I just use some gems, like sass, compass, etc..

Was looking around, but couldn't find a solution, I see other people get some kind of error, but I get nothing, it's just stuck.

Any advice?
Maybe delete gems and reinstall them?

```
$ gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.2.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2014-02-24 patchlevel 451) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/xyz/.gem/specs
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-13
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
     - /Users/xyz/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
```

Comment: Guess this could happen if a test case in the bundle gets stuck (happened to me when installing `rubinius`). Managed to find the installation command hierarchy and the specific 'hung' process via `ps -ef`, then killed it, and directly ran the installation command from the downloaded temp. source directory (`rake build install` instead of `rake`, bypassing the tests)

Answer (score 10):

When `gem` says *Building native extensions*, that means it's compiling some C code in order to [bundle an extension along with the given gem](http://guides.rubygems.org/gems-with-extensions/).  Your fans going to 6k is probably the result of processor intensive compilation - as in, compiling the extension uses quite a bit of your processor.

I would watch your processes to make sure that it's being at least compiled.

Comment: I know that thanks, but something is wrong here, it doesn't get compiled it stucks on this, I can wait for hours.
Things is there are no errors it's just same screen all the time.

Comment: Alright, add the `--verbose` flag to the command line and see what you get

Comment: This is what i get: http://pastebin.com/bMiyJXsN and it just stucks, nothing happens, but I see my CPU is like doing something or is trying to do something.

Comment: I have hit cancel after some time, I do get error: http://pastebin.com/3FR2u7xh

I have tried a search for this log file, there are few of them: http://pastebin.com/u3iAdw9L

should I check them all, looks like few gems cannot compile?

Comment: as @JeremyRodi said. compilation is CPU intensive and can take some time.